# AR core loading prefabs dynamically in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I have recently started dabbling in Unity with ARcore, I am using the HelloARController.cs that comes with ARcore 1.5 but I want to load a bundle from my server, I have two scripts

one called LoadAsset.cs which loads a bundle from a webserver and I have another called HelloARcontroller.cs which is basically the main part of the app, this allows me to preset prefabs that will be loaded when the screen is clicked

What I would like to do instead of loading one of the "Andy" objects is for it to pull a prefab from the webserver and use that instead

I have managed so far to load a prefab from my server at runtime but placing it is another matter

```
namespace GoogleARCore.Examples.HelloAR
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GoogleARCore;
using GoogleARCore.Examples.Common;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
// Set up touch input propagation while using Instant Preview in the editor.
using Input = InstantPreviewInput;
#endif

/// <summary>
/// Controls the HelloAR example.
/// </summary>
public class HelloARController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string BundleURL; // --> 
http://Myserver/public_http/Assets/AssetBundles/cube_prefab (path to the AssetBundle)
    public string AssetName; // --> Cube_pref (name of the Asset prefab)
    public int version;

    /// <summary>
    /// The first-person camera being used to render the passthrough camera image (i.e. AR background).
    /// </summary>
    public Camera FirstPersonCamera;

    /// <summary>
    /// A prefab for tracking and visualizing detected planes.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject DetectedPlanePrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model to place when a raycast from a user touch hits a plane.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject AndyPlanePrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model to place when a raycast from a user touch hits a feature point.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject AndyPointPrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// A gameobject parenting UI for displaying the "searching for planes" snackbar.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject SearchingForPlaneUI;

    /// <summary>
    /// The rotation in degrees need to apply to model when the Andy model is placed.
    /// </summary>
    private const float k_ModelRotation = 180.0f;

    /// <summary>
    /// A list to hold all planes ARCore is tracking in the current frame. This object is used across
    /// the application to avoid per-frame allocations.
    /// </summary>
    private List<DetectedPlane> m_AllPlanes = new List<DetectedPlane>();

    /// <summary>
    /// True if the app is in the process of quitting due to an ARCore connection error, otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_IsQuitting = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unity Update() method.
    /// </summary>


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndCache()
    {
        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(BundleURL, version))
        {
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            GameObject testing = bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName) as GameObject;


            // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
            bundle.Unload(false);
        } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
    }
```

I've declared all my variables and managed to get the Prefab to load up to this point ^^^^^

```
    public void Update()
    {
        _UpdateApplicationLifecycle();

        // Hide snackbar when currently tracking at least one plane.
        Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_AllPlanes);
        bool showSearchingUI = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_AllPlanes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (m_AllPlanes[i].TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                showSearchingUI = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SearchingForPlaneUI.SetActive(showSearchingUI);

        // If the player has not touched the screen, we are done with this update.
        Touch touch;
        if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
        TrackableHit hit;
        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
            TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
        {
            // Use hit pose and camera pose to check if hittest is from the
            // back of the plane, if it is, no need to create the anchor.
            if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
                Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
                    hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
            }
            else
            {
```

This is where it loads the Andy prefabs, what I would like to do is swap the andy prefab out for the asset bundle 
                    // Choose the Andy model for the Trackable that got hit.
                    GameObject prefab;
                    if (hit.Trackable is FeaturePoint)
                    {
                        prefab = AndyPlanePrefab;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prefab = AndyPointPrefab;
                    }

```
                // Instantiate Andy model at the hit pose.
                var andyObject = Instantiate(prefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);


                // Compensate for the hitPose rotation facing away from the raycast (i.e. camera).
                andyObject.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);

                // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
                // world evolves.
                var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

                // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
                andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check and update the application lifecycle.
    /// </summary>
    private void _UpdateApplicationLifecycle()
    {
        // Exit the app when the 'back' button is pressed.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        // Only allow the screen to sleep when not tracking.
        if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
        {
            const int lostTrackingSleepTimeout = 15;
            Screen.sleepTimeout = lostTrackingSleepTimeout;
        }
        else
        {
            Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
        }

        if (m_IsQuitting)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Quit if ARCore was unable to connect and give Unity some time for the toast to appear.
        if (Session.Status == SessionStatus.ErrorPermissionNotGranted)
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Camera permission is needed to run this application.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
        else if (Session.Status.IsError())
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("ARCore encountered a problem connecting.  Please start the app again.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Actually quit the application.
    /// </summary>
    private void _DoQuit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show an Android toast message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">Message string to show in the toast.</param>
    private void _ShowAndroidToastMessage(string message)
    {
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        if (unityActivity != null)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass toastClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
            unityActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
            {
                AndroidJavaObject toastObject = toastClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", unityActivity,
                    message, 0);
                toastObject.Call("show");
            }));
        }
    }
}
}
```

My plan is to change the URL dynamically as thats just a public variable so that I can load a different prefab once the app is running, then change the url and load a different prefab.

Any help, advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to download the prefabs during runtime?

Comment: I want to be able to select from a list and there may be several hundred prefabs, to store these all locally would require massive amounts of space on the phone/device and would make it practically un-usable